# rosjava install uri

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found two different rosjava install uri

The one in the rosjava tutorial: https://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg

AND

The one in googlecode page: https://code.google.com/p/rosjava/

Is there any difference between these two uris and which one should i use?

Thanks a lot :>

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30109/rosjava-install-uri/) by [ira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1953/ira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2012-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The two URIs are equivalent. I believe the SSL cert is assigned to the https://code.google.com/p/rosjava/ one though and hg may complain if you use the other. However, that shouldn't be a problem unless you're trying to push to the repo.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1